# How to query in a specific document in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some code that gets a collection reference to the users collection and then queries an animeID field whether it contains a certain value or not. I want to change this and only query inside the document with the id i pass. So if you look at the picture of my firestore you can see that i have two documents inside the users collection each with their unique id. I want to query for the animeID field only in the document that i want. Not all the documents as it does right now. How would i go about doing this? I have tried using doc and then passing in the id of the document but i don't think query works on doc as it gives me an error. Thanks

```
const docRef = collection(db, 'users')
  const q = query(docRef, where('animeID', 'array-contains', parseInt(id)))
  onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      results.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
    })
    if(results.length > 0){
      console.log(true)
    }
    else{
      console.log(false)
    }
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

**Firestore structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=2#get_a_document):

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "users", "dbmbEiR6....");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  const animeID = docSnap.data().animeID;
  // Do whatever you want with animeID
  // E.g. log its value:
  console.log(JSON.stringify(animeID));
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

---

So you don't need to declare a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query?authuser=2) in this case. Just declare a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference?authuser=2) and use the `getDoc()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So that gets me a reference to the document i want but i also need to query from that document the animeID field.  I don't just want to see if the document exists or not i need to go a deeper level and see if the animeID field matches the id i provide inside the document with the id i also provide. Sorry for the long explanation. Thanks.

Comment: See the update.